# I can't turn off/pause automatic slideshow when there is only 1 picture (using lightbox2)

Tags: javascript

I am using lightbox2 and it is a wonderful module. The only issue that I have is that I cannot seem to find a way to turn off the automatic diashow when there is only 1 picture.

When 5 pictures are added to a blogmessage there is a slideshow, 1 by 1 the pictures are shown. This can be paused in case someone wants to have a longer look at a picture.
When there is only 1 picture it is not possible to pause. It is possible but I have to configure a button, standard is Space button. But my users do not know this. How can achieve this without a keyboard key?

**What I want:**
I want to make sure that when there is only 1 picture it can also be paused. So you don't have to click on the thumbnail of the picture again to see it in deatil.

I hope that is somewhat clear.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There was an option that I overlooked: Close slideshow automatically (when the last picture is shown).
So solved.

Answer (score -1):

when there is only one picture then it won't go off untill click somewhere else on the screen ... for better understanding go to lightbox configurations...

Comment: Can you elaborate on this a little?  Does configuration affect this?  Is this explained on the configuration page?

Comment: It does try load to a new picture, but there is noone so the imagepopup of lightbox just closes. Which is not cool because you have to reclick the thumbnail to see the picture in detail. I cannot seem to find it in the configuration. I'll have another look.

Comment: i have implemented same lightbox2 on my new drupal installation it works fine . & it does not try load a new picture but u r having the problem so try a new lightbox2 in a fesh drupal7 install.

Comment: Got it, was an option that I had checked in the past for some reason probably. (see comment on my own post). Thanks for looking into it :)